# Pandas: Binning a time serie by yearly percentiles

Tags: python, pandas, binning

I have the following dataframe:

```
date  = ['2015-02-03 23:00:00','2015-02-03 23:30:00','2015-02-04 00:00:00','2015-02-04 00:30:00','2015-02-04 01:00:00','2015-02-04 01:30:00','2015-02-04 02:00:00','2015-02-04 02:30:00','2015-02-04 03:00:00','2015-02-04 03:30:00','2015-02-04 04:00:00','2015-02-04 04:30:00','2015-02-04 05:00:00','2015-02-04 05:30:00','2015-02-04 06:00:00','2015-02-04 06:30:00','2015-02-04 07:00:00','2015-02-04 07:30:00','2015-02-04 08:00:00','2015-02-04 08:30:00','2015-02-04 09:00:00','2015-02-04 09:30:00','2015-02-04 10:00:00','2015-02-04 10:30:00','2015-02-04 11:00:00','2015-02-04 11:30:00','2015-02-04 12:00:00','2015-02-04 12:30:00','2015-02-04 13:00:00','2015-02-04 13:30:00','2015-02-04 14:00:00','2015-02-04 14:30:00','2015-02-04 15:00:00','2015-02-04 15:30:00','2015-02-04 16:00:00','2015-02-04 16:30:00','2015-02-04 17:00:00','2015-02-04 17:30:00','2015-02-04 18:00:00','2015-02-04 18:30:00','2015-02-04 19:00:00','2015-02-04 19:30:00','2015-02-04 20:00:00','2015-02-04 20:30:00','2015-02-04 21:00:00','2015-02-04 21:30:00','2015-02-04 22:00:00','2015-02-04 22:30:00','2015-02-04 23:00:00','2015-02-04 23:30:00']
value = [33.24  , 31.71  , 34.39  , 34.49  , 34.67  , 34.46  , 34.59  , 34.83  , 35.78  , 33.03  , 35.49  , 33.79  , 36.12  , 37.09  , 39.54  , 41.19  , 45.99  , 50.23  , 46.72  , 47.47  , 48.46  , 48.38  , 48.40  , 48.13  , 38.35  , 38.19  , 38.12  , 38.05  , 38.06  , 37.83  , 37.49  , 37.41 , 41.84  , 42.26 , 44.09  , 48.85  , 50.07 , 50.94  , 51.09  , 50.60  , 47.39  , 45.57  , 45.03  , 44.98  , 41.32  , 40.37  , 41.12  , 39.33  , 35.38  , 33.44  ]
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':value,'index':date})
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['index'],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
df.drop(['index'],axis=1,inplace=True)
print(df)    

                     value
index                     
2015-02-03 23:00:00  33.24
2015-02-03 23:30:00  31.71
2015-02-04 00:00:00  34.39
2015-02-04 00:30:00  34.49
2015-02-04 01:00:00  34.67
2015-02-04 01:30:00  34.46
```

I would like to bin the value column to see if the value is superior to the 90% percentile of values for that year or in between the 80% and 90% percentile not included of that year.

I know I can use pandas cut function, my problem is how to pass in the given percentiles of each year into it (the variables called 'PERCENTILE80_of_considered_year' and 'PERCENTILE90_of_considered_year'):

```
binned = pd.cut(x=df.value, bins=[-np.inf,PERCENTILE80_of_considered_year, PERCENTILE90_of_considered_year, np.inf], right=False, labels=['<P80', 'P80_90', '>P90'])
```

The expected result would be something like (only illustrative):

```
                     value   bin
index                     
2015-02-03 23:00:00  33.24   P80_90 
2015-02-03 23:30:00  31.71   <P80
2015-02-04 00:00:00  34.39   P80_90
2015-02-04 00:30:00  34.49  P80_90
2015-02-04 01:00:00  34.67   >P90
2015-02-04 01:30:00  34.46   P80_90
```

Does anyone know how to do that efficiently? Or any other approach that would be efficient?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I get your question completely, but I would calculate the percentiles as follows:

```
p80 = df.value.quantile(0.8)
p90= df.value.quantile(0.9)
df['binned'] = pd.cut(x=df.value, bins=[-np.inf, p80, p90, np.inf], right=False, labels=['<P80', 'P80_90', '>P90'])
```

Your example has only one year, in case of multiple years you could do the same but on `groups` rather than a full `df`. Many ways to do this, but one option is:

```
for year in df.index.year.unique():
   mask = df.index.year == year
   df.loc[mask, 'binned'] = pd.cut(x=df.value 
               , bins=[-np.inf, df[mask].value.quantile(0.8), df[mask].value.quantile(0.9), np.inf]
                , right=False, labels=['<P80', 'P80_90', '>P90'])
df.head()
```

Comment: I want to do exactly that but with multiple years. How would you do it on groups? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can `groupby` year and `apply` a function to each group.

```
def get_bin(group):
    p80 = group.value.quantile(0.8)
    p90 = group.value.quantile(0.9)

    group['bin'] = pd.cut(
        x=group.value,
        bins=[-np.inf, p80, p90, np.inf],
        right=False,
        labels=['<P80', 'P80_90', '>P90'])
    return group

df.groupby(lambda x: x.year).apply(get_bin)

#                      value     bin
# index
# 2015-02-03 23:00:00  33.24    <P80
# 2015-02-04 07:00:00  45.99    <P80
# 2015-02-04 07:30:00  50.23    >P90
# 2015-02-04 09:00:00  48.46  P80_90
# 2015-02-04 10:00:00  48.40  P80_90
```